# Jersey errors trying to load class

Tags: maven, jersey, shiro

I'm trying to move from jersey 1.17 to 2.31 (min).  My code was working before but now I need to move my jersey up a few versions as I need to use Client and WebTarget classes that are in jaxrs 2.0 and the 1.17 jersey is causing some errors.

---

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId> 
  <version>1.17</version>
 </dependency> -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <!--<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.17</version>
 </dependency> -->
 <!-- <dependency> 
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.17</version>
 </dependency> -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

and my web.xml is like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
<!-- <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> -->
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <!-- <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> -->
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mycomp.stuff.interfaces</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>debug</param-name>
     <param-value>0</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

And before container even gets close to my code I get this in my log file ~5 times:

`*_Feb 03, 2014 5:45:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.glassfish.hk2.internal.PerThreadContext$1.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1588)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$4.run(Utilities.java:1239)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$4.run(Utilities.java:1235)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getAllConstructorKeys(Utilities.java:1235)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getAllConstructors(Utilities.java:1222)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findProducerConstructor(Utilities.java:1141)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:73)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:143)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:157)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:125)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:176)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:647)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:602)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:377)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1780)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1103)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1050)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$5.run(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1029)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$5.run(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1025)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.protectedGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1025)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.resolveContext(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1683)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorImpl.intercept(MethodInterceptorImpl.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.UriInfoInjectee$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$453ec21b.finalize(<generated>)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:101)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:32)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:190)_*
```

Any ideas why this is happening or can somebody point me in the right direction to interrogate this further? And why is this happening now, when all that was changes in configuration files?

Comment: Are you using tomcat? Have you restarted the server and ensured any cached old version of your app has been removed before you restart?

Comment: Yes, I'm using tomcat as the jersey-glassfish servlet container. I usually undeploy the previous war file then deploy it again using the tomcat manager screen's 'deployment' fields